# ITextViewer: How to highlight a whole line?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

In my eclipse plugin, I have a ITextViewer object and a line number. What I want to do is to color the whole line at the line number.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you in complete control of the `ITextViewer` object (did you create the `TextViewer` yourself) or is this a text viewer belonging to an existing text editor?

Comment: @greg-449 The ITextViewer comes from a IEditorPart

Comment: If it is from an existing editor it is probably using the full Eclipse SourceViewer, SourceViewerConfiguration, presentation damager / reparier, presentation reconciler system. You will have to look at what extension points the editor supports to see what it supports for extending its existing coloring code.